# Import csv file in powershell with numeric headers

Tags: powershell, csv

Can somebody tell me how to read a csv file with numeric headers in powershell
Eg:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6 
 value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
 value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
 value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
```

I tried following

```
$csvObject = Import-Csv -Path <file name>
ForEach ($dataRow in $csvObject) {
  $val1 = $dataRow.1
  Write-Host $val1
}
```

and it didn't work, can someone guide me how should I read this file?

Comment: Error message? Symptoms of failure?

Comment: I've just tried it and it works as expected on PowerShell 4; Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Thanks @andyb and @TessellatingHeckler. Actually bit newbie to powershell, I could done it with the way I did it, only issue occurred when I tries to get the value in upper case. Eg: $dataRow.1
.ToUpper(). Powershell ISE showed that as an error. To fix it, I changed it as `$dataRow."1".ToUpper()`. Everything works as expected now. Thanks for your time again. Oh what am I gonna do with this question now

Comment: I almost suggested quoting the 1 until I tried it and found it didn't need it to do a basic lookup. Good that you solved it - I suggest you post what you did as an answer and accept your own answer; that's an acceptable thing to do on Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, issue was when I tried to use value as upper case, powershell ISE showed me it as syntax error. so I changed it to `$dataRow."1".ToUpper()` instead `$dataRow.1.ToUpper()`.

Thanks.